# Openlayer 5.3 : select part of gpx/kml

Tags: openlayers, kml, gpx, route

I created a page where people can upload a gpx or kml file. Openlayers makes this a piece of cake.

But now I would like to provide some kind of editing to select a piece of the multilinestring.

What I was thinking

- people can select a piece by putting two points on the route. "The system" copies the selected piece (between the two points) to a new source
- people can trace a route. They click on the route to set a starting point, they move along the route (with snapping) and a final click to set a ending point.
- people click to set a starting point, they move along the route (with snapping) and click to add a point on a turn and double click to end the draw

I have no problems with loading the file, adding snapping, drawing and editing. I'm looking for tips on a strategy to do the final part.

The last idea is probable the simpliest but i want to avoid that one (and probably the second idea for the same reason). In case of long routes it would take a lot of time and i don't want people giving up because it takes to long or is to much work.

I was wondering what other ideas are out there. Some code would be good but a push in the right direction is ok.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked "to broad" and how i can be more specific. I want to copy a piece of a multilinestring and i'm asking what's the best to achieve this. I have been thinking about the problem and put my ideas in the post. But since there are far more experienced openlayer users, i was wondering if there are some other solutions. Something that hasn't crossed my mind